# How to insert multiple time series in one millisecond in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

How to write multiple time series of data to Apache IoTDB in the same millisecond? Do I need to consider the design of the data structure of the time series? Or what can I change to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modiy the timestamp of inserting data into Apache IoTDB to nanoseconds or microseconds, and see if this can satisfy your needs.